# Force correct order of tables and figures (in appendix)?

Tags: floats, memoir, appendices

I'm working in the `\appendix` environment of a `memoir`-class document. In the appendix, I have a number of tables:

1. `\begin{table} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{table}`
2. `\begin{table} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{table}`
3. `\begin{landscape} \begin{longtable}{...} ... \end{longtable} \end{landscape}`
4. `\begin{landscape} \begin{longtable}{...} ... \end{longtable} \end{landscape}`
5. `\begin{table} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{table}`

After that, I'd like to display a figure: `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`. I definitely want that shown after all the tables in the document. However, it always appears between tables 4 and 5 in the PDF, even though it would fit very nicely.

I've already tried forcing things with `\begin{figure}[h!]` and/or `\begin{table}[h!]` for table 5. `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` in front of `\begin{figure}` won't do the trick either.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Have you tried using a `\clearpage` command? This will flush floats waiting to be output.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `flafter` package (part of the base LaTeX distribution) then floats will always appear after their position in the source. So if the source of your figure is on or after the page with the last table, it will not move "back" to the top of that page, even if `t` floats are allowed.

Comment: That looks like an interesting package. Does it switch off floating  completely or can the author choose (e.g. in the form of an environment) in which part of the document the floating shall be disabled?

Comment: @Roman no it just modifies the float algorithm not to allow `t` on the first attempted page, which is the only time a float ever moves "backwards"

Answer (score 5):

Putting `\FloatBarrier` between the figures and tables should also prevent them from floating. The function is provided by the package `placeins`.